# how to transfer log files from cloudwatch logs to redshift

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, local, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Anybody have any idea? please help

Answer (score 0):

Though question is very generic and constrained are not specified, hence there could be multiple solutions. But in my opinion, following could be good approach.

1. Export Cloudwatch Logs to S3
2. Copy logs from S3  to Redshift using Copy command

Here are some basic information about Step #1.

This step could be performed either of following ways.

- Stream logs directly to S3 Using CloudWatch Logs Subscription Filters
- Use a CloudWatch Scheduled event to schedule a Lambda function to run a log export to S3. Few documentation that could help.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html

https://source.sh/blog/2015/06/06/automatically-exporting-cloudwatch-logs-to-s3-with-kinesis-and-lambda/

Here are some basic information about Step #2
There is good documentation about Copy commands, refer below link. You could use any languages/liberaries of your choice, python/shell-script,java and boto3 etc to excute `copy sql command`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-S3.html

Comment: yeah it solved the problem.Can you please help me for the above mentioned issue?

Comment: Updated question is completely different from previous one, it makes answer way off. You should revert question to original and ask current question as new question. Asking completely different question in update is not correct practice  at stackoverflow.